# Hochschild homology and change of non-ground ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, hochschild-homology

Let $k$ be a field, $R$ is a commutative algebra over $k$ and $A$ is an associative algebra over $R$. There is a morphism of commutative algebras $R \to T$. Is it possible to reduce calculation of Hochschild homology $HH_*(A\otimes_R T)$ (over basic field $k$) to $HH_*(A)$? I'm mostly interested in a situation when $T$ is separable over $R$, or even more specific $T=R/I$.

Comment: If A is flat over R, or more generally $Tor^R(A,T) = 0$ in positive degrees, then there is a spectral sequence starting with $Tor^{HH_* R}(HH_* A, HH_* T)$ converging to your desired Hochschild term.  Does that work in your situation?

Comment: Yes, it looks like something that could be very useful for me.

Comment: @Tyler Could you please give a reference for this spectral sequence?

Comment: @Sasha: I'm afraid that I don't have a ready reference.  You can prove it by constructing a double complex whose rows are the Hochschild complexes of $A \otimes R^{\otimes q} \otimes T$, with vertical differentials coming from the bar construction.  (It's essentially the Hochschild complex of the DGA $A \otimes^{\mathbb L}_R T$.)

Answer (score 4):

According to the following paper:

Geller, S.; Weibel, C.: 
Étale descent for Hochschild and cyclic homology, 
*Comment. Math. Helv.* **66** (1991), no. 3, 368–388;

—theorem (0.1)— you need that $T$ is *étale* over $R$. This holds in your case only if the ideal $I$ is generated by an idempotent. Notice that "étale" = "unramified + flat". And the notion of unramifiedness is related to the condition of separable ring extension, but it depends on which of the several used definitions of "separable" you consider.

Comment: For me, separable means that $T$ is projective over $T \otimes_R T$. 
I'm aware of this result, but situation when $I$ is generated by an idempotent is not useful for me.

Comment: Without flatness I have the intuition the result is false. Sorry about that.

Comment: Probably won't help, but just a remark in case it's helpful that the etale descent statement extends to smooth descent.

Comment: @David Can you give a reference for this?

Comment: @Leo: http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3636 Proposition 1.26